# Какова реализация System.arraycopy?

Tags: java, jvm, java.lang.system

Назрел вопрос, как реализован `System.arraycopy()` в Java?

Всем известно, что встроенный метод `System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 0, 2)` параметры, которого есть, массив из которого будем копировать, начиная с какого элемента, массив в который будем копировать, начиная с какого элемента и сколько элементов.

Очевидно, что работа при **n > 100** элементов, по скорость превышает копирование циклом. Так в чем же секрет? Получается, что метод копирует данные блоками?

Comment: Некоторые методы из jdk при компиляции заменяются быстрыми низкоуровневыми вызовами, а код, который вы смотрите в IDE - для отладки. Еще, например, сравнение строк будет быстрее сравнения "вручную"

Comment: хотелось хотя бы немного, узнать про эти вызовы

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если пробежаться по [исходникам OpenJDK](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509), легко убедится, что `System.arraycopy` - это просто [memmove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/) обёрнутая пелёнкой проверок.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, где лежит конкретно реализация метода, в какой папке ? Я пока ищу, найти не могу.

Comment: JVM - сложная система, не стоит ожидать, что весь интересующий вас код будет лежать в одном месте. Это будет цепочка макросов и функций, разбросанных по нескольким файлам. Причём самые низкоуровневые из них будут зависеть от платформы, для которой JVM компилируется. Клонируйте себе исходники, grep'ом найдите `JVM_ArrayCopy` и дальше идите по цепочке вызовов.